# how to fire google tag manager custom events with data layer

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

how to add google analytics in my chrome extension, in react js ..
i want to fire some custom event when my specific  condition is  satisfy and I want to show in google analytics .
please guide me step by step

Answer (score 0):

In order to integrate Google Analytics into your React app, you first have to create the respective GA Property (which I am sure you have already done on the Google Analytics website). Then copy the script that Google Analytics provides and add a script element into the body of your React app that contains the copied script at runtime.

I wrote an article explaining exactly this problem in-depth, [you can read it here](https://blog.cetindere.de/integrate-google-analytics-into-your-react-web-app/).